# macOS Sierra doesn’t seem to remember SSH keys between reboots

Tags: terminal, password, ssh, macos

I have to run this command since upgrading to macOS:

```
ssh-add -K
```

Corrects the problem after the reboot but I have to run this command every time I log on to my computer.

If I do not run the command above, my keys in `~/.ssh` are skipped and I am being asked server password in order to establish the connection.

Comment: `$ ssh-add -K` gives me `ssh-add: illegal option -- K`

Comment: You will need to enter the private key path after `-K`. See @JakeGould 's answer for resolution.

Comment: The 10.12.2 update eliminated some unnecessary server password requests for me. You may now no longer need to run the ssh-add -K.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

Comment: @modius Make sure you are running the correct version of `ssh-add`: It should be `/usr/bin/ssh-add`, not something installed by homebrew, conda, etc.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Apple added an `ssh_config` option called `UseKeychain` which allows a 'proper' resolution to the problem. Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
```

From the `ssh_config` `man` page on 10.12.2:

> **UseKeychain**
>
> On macOS, specifies whether the system should search for passphrases in the user's keychain when attempting to use a particular key. When the passphrase is provided by the user, this option also specifies whether the passphrase should be stored into the keychain once it has been verified to be correct.  The argument must be 'yes' or 'no'.  The default is 'no'.

Comment: According to this link: https://openradar.appspot.com/27348363 Apple has "re-aligned [their] behavior with the mainstream OpenSSH in this area".

Comment: It's absurd that Apple modified behaviour in a way which will cause issues for the vast majority of developers (because of GitHub push if nothing else) and said nothing to anyone!

Comment: I think the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` is redundant and not needed (when looking at default options). I've never set that option in my ssh config file.

Comment: @JakeGould IMO changing `~/.ssh/config~` is preferable as it solves the problem at the `ssh` level. Not 100% sure that the `.bash_profile` mod will work for GUI clients using ssh without using a shell.

Comment: Apple published [Technical Note TN2449](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) regarding that change.

Comment: The mention of `id_rsa` in this answer is confusing.

Comment: @commonpike @therealmarv I've removed the `IdentityFile` option from the answer as it's not required.

Comment: Also works on 10.13

Comment: As I mentioned over at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically#comment401317_250572: Apple advises using `IgnoreUnknown UseKeychain` for cross-compatibility with Linux

Comment: Some of the key reasons that adding `UseKeychain yes` to the .ssh/config file for each key is a better method than using `ssh-add`: 1. It's supported and recommended. 2. It doesn't rely on the shell like adding to `.bash_profile` would. 3. It allows you *not* to automatically add the passphrase for a particularly sensitive key. 4. If you add a new key you will likely need to edit the `config` file anyway, so you can do everything in one place.

Comment: Does setting `UseKeychain yes` cause the passphrase to be saved across reboots (i.e. written to disk)?  If so, is there a way to prevent this from happening?  I don't see how it's a good idea to save an SSH passphrase in a potentially less-secure location.

Comment: @intuited the passphrase is saved to disk in the user's keychain (that's what `UseKeychain yes` means). The macOS keychains are securely encrypted. If you don't want them saved to the keychain, then set this option to no, but then obviously passphrases are *not* persisted across reboots, which is what this question is all about.

Comment: The config file wasn't even there for me. I had to add it myself

Comment: The preceding `Host *` line is unnecessary. Any options not under a `Host` will be considered global configs.

Answer (score 124):

I had this issue as well when attempting to deploy some code using [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/). Very frustrating. Here are two methods I know of to deal with this issue.

#### Method 1: Add *all known* keys to the SSH agent.

So one solution I found is to run [`ssh-add`](http://capistranorb.com/) with the `-A` option—which adds all known identities to the SSH agent using any passphrases stored in your keychain—like this:

```
ssh-add -A
```

Now this works but it won’t persist across reboots. So if you want to never worry about this again, just open up your user’s `~/.bash_profile` file like this:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this line to the bottom:

```
ssh-add -A 2>/dev/null;
```

Now when you open a new Terminal window, all should be good!

#### Method 2: Add *only SSH keys that are in the keychain* to the agent.

So while the `ssh-add -A` option should work for most basic cases, I ran into an issue recently where I had 6-7 Vagrant boxes (which uses SSH keys/identities for access) setup on a machine on top of the more common `id_rsa.pub` in place.

Long story short, I ended up being locked out of a remote server due to too many failed tries based on SSH keys/identities since the server access was based on a password and SSH keys/identities are SSH keys/identities. So the SSH agent tried *all* of my SSH keys, failed and I couldn’t even get to the password prompt.

The problem is that `ssh-add -A` will just arbitrarily add every single SSH key/identity you have to the agent even if it’s not necessary to do so; such as in the case of Vagrant boxes.

My solution after much testing was as follows.

First, if you have more SSH keys/identities added to your agent than you need—as shown with `ssh-add -l` then purge them all from the agent like so:

```
ssh-add -D
```

With that done, then start the SSH agent as a background process like so:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Now, it gets weird and I am not too sure why. In some cases you can specifically add the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key/identity to the agent like so:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Type in your passphrase, hit <kbd>Return</kbd> and you should be good to go.

But in other cases simply running this is enough to get the key/identity added:

```
ssh-add -K
```

If that’s all worked, type in `ssh-add -l` and you should see one lone SSH key/identity listed.

All good? Now open up your `.bash_profile`:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And add this line to the bottom; comment or remove the `-A` version if you have that in place:

```
ssh-add -K 2>/dev/null;
```

That will allow the SSH key/identity to be reloaded to the SSH agent on each startup/reboot.

#### UPDATE: Apple has now added a `UseKeychain` option to the open SSH config options and considers `ssh-add -A` a solution as well.

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.2, [Apple has added a `UseKeychain` config option](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html) for SSH configs. Checking the man page (via `man ssh_config`) shows the following info:

```
UseKeychain
        On macOS, specifies whether the system should search for
        passphrases in the user's keychain when attempting to use a par-
        ticular key. When the passphrase is provided by the user, this
        option also specifies whether the passphrase should be stored
        into the keychain once it has been verified to be correct.  The
        argument must be ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

Which boils down to Apple seeing the solution as either adding `ssh-add -A` to your `.bash_profile` [as explained in this Open Radar ticket](https://openradar.appspot.com/27348363) or adding `UseKeychain` as one of the options in a per user `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; but i have a passphrase on the key.

Comment: @modius: if you have a pw protected key, do `ssh-add -K [path to key]` and enter pw when prompted. Keychain will store password and ssh-add will get it from there after that.

Comment: Note the -A is for adding identities to the agent using any passphrases stored in your keychain. If you additionally have identities without passphrases, you will need to omit the -A option to add them to your agent.

Comment: Just to add a bit more visibility to this, Apple has update the man page for ssh_config to include `UseKeychain` and `AddKeysToAgent` to automatically add your keys from your ssh_config. No shell scripting needed. See @mluisbrown answer below for the updated info for 10.12.2

Comment: @JakeGould I get what you are saying, I actually like what they are doing. Instead of automatically saving the passphrase to the Keychain and loading it on boot, they are giving you control of your security. /shrug

Comment: LOL, thanks for that - So they add in ssh_config options to handle this automatically but don't recommend using them.

Comment: it's worth noting that the UseKeychain option doesn't work if one is using the ssh installed with homebrew

Comment: `ssh-add -A` doesn't work on Mojave (10.14.6 (18G4032)), with fresh ssh-add (/usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.3p1/bin/ssh-add). It seems like it's working with these 2 (using the fresh ssh-add):
`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa` then 
`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: One more comment: make sure you are using `/usr/bin/ssh-add` and not something installed by homebrew, conda, etc.  (Check `which ssh-add` to be sure.)

Answer (score 24):

As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html), this is the recommended method since *macOS 10.12.2*:

1. Add the following lines to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

   ```
   Host *
       UseKeychain yes
       AddKeysToAgent yes
   ```
2. Any key you add to the *ssh-agent* using the `ssh-add /path/to/your/private/key/id_rsa` command will be automatically added to the keychain, and should be autoloaded upon reboot.

---

I'm adding this answer because:

- Other answers tell you to add the `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` line, but that option is not needed for autoloading the keys (and it'll actually bind that particular key for the host section your add it to, which you won't want if you use different keys for different hots).
- The accepted answer mentions `UseKeychain`, but that is not enough to persist the keys in `ssh-agent` after a reboot.

Comment: Regarding second point. Just how sure are you? Nothing actually happens upon reboot and it is not mentioned in your reference material either. What does happen with the above config is that your SSH client will load the key into agent *upon first connection* (and it will also fetch the passphrase from keychain), then the key will stay loaded. You can verify this statement by listing the keys right after reboot via `ssh-add -L` and it will report `The agent has no identities`. Nothing will be there until you connect. The `AddKeysToAgent` does not persist keys between reboots in any way!

Answer (score 16):

I've written [a short post about this topic](https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain) that might help you.

A solution is calling `ssh-add -A` command on every startup.

Just add `.plist` file with the following content to the path `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` or create one with [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>ssh-add-a</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>ssh-add</string>
        <string>-A</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

<!-- @@@@LingonWhatStart:ssh-add -A@@@@LingonWhatEnd -->
```

Answer (score 8):

Since macOS 10.12.2 you can use the `UseKeychain` option. 
[Read more here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017589) or look into `man ssh_config`.

```
     UseKeychain
         On macOS, specifies whether the system should search for passphrases in the user's keychain
         when attempting to use a particular key. When the passphrase is provided by the user, this
         option also specifies whether the passphrase should be stored into the keychain once it has
         been verified to be correct.  The argument must be ``yes'' or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
```

**So just do the following:**

`echo "UseKeychain yes" >> ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: Using `>>` is at risk if you input the command multiple times. Better do a manual edition of the file, as described by [mluisbrown answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264974/62697) or [ChrisJF answer](https://superuser.com/a/1163862/214362).

Comment: You are right there :-)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem before and I've found a way to bypass this. I just created a file named `config` in my `~/.ssh` folder, where I've added the following lines:

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I am not sure why, but `Host` and `HostName` both are important. In my case if one of them was not present then the solution didn't work.

Then, I just did an `ssh-add -K` and it was working even after the restart.

Comment: Host is your user-defined name/alias for a particular server and demarcates  entries per server: stylistically it's nice to indent the lines that follow the Host entry. HostName indicates the server's network addressable name like github.com, but you could use an IP address too. Host and HostName don't have to be the same thing, but yes, they are both integral to the ssh config format.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a different version of ssh (e.g. installed via homebrew) the above solutions will not work out of the box. For instance, `AddKeysToAgent yes` and `UseKeychain yes` in the `.ssh/config` file are not recognized by non-Apple ssh versions and will cause an error. The same for the `-A` or `-K` option for the `ssh` client.

That means [@mluisbrown](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264974/45492)'s answer will not work at all. You can use method 1 of [@Giacomo1968](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254714/45492)'s answer and explicitly use the macOS `ssh-add` utility in your `.bash_profile` to add all keys to the keychain, i.e.:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add -A
```

As mentioned by a [comment above](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots/254714#comment318402_254714), you may have to add a key to the keychain first: e.g. `/usr/bin/ssh-add -K .ssh/github`

Answer (score 4):

I found that `ssh-add -K` gave me "**illegal option -- K**".
This was because ssh-add was a strange version coming from /usr/local/bin (installed by brew?). I was able to add the key by specific use of the ssh-add located in /usr/bin:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: this is what worked fro me after failing to work easily for ages.

Answer (score 3):

I updated to Mac OS X Sierra (10.12.6). I could ssh into other hosts but not into github.com.

This is what I had to insert into ~/.ssh/config:

```
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
```

After that change, I could use github as before.

Comment: This finally solved all my SSH problems on Mac OS 13.3 when trying to connect to a Hostgator server (after using `ssh-copy-id` to copy the id to the server).

Answer (score 2):

Amending ~/.ssh/config to add UseKeyChain for all hosts 
is enough to stop this recurring nightmare ;)

```
Host *
 UseKeychain yes
```

If the file is empty or doesn't exist simple create and/or add the above configuration.

Comment: Could you explain how this works.
for example when ssh-add is run or on reboot.
what actually happens?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question answered in this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363404/ssh-add-command-does-not-add-my-identity-to-ssh-agent?newreg=19302549832042f7a84938fdef3c981d) on Askubuntu. I found a great solution for that by adding a plugin for oh-my-zsh shell that I switched to from bash.