# macOS Sierra: Why do I have to enter the password for my private key?

Tags: ssh, macos

I recently upgraded my computer to macOS Sierra. Everything went fine, but somewhere along the way something got changed (probably something I did) and now every time I try to ssh into another machine the terminal prompts me to enter my password. If I type the password and enter it the ssh session works as normal. But why do I have to enter my password at all? What can I do to fix this?

Side note: I have tried changing the file permissions to no avail. They are currently 644 like the public key.

Comment: private key should be `chmod 400` add a -v and see if it's using your key

Comment: Done! Thanks. Problem still exists. Yes, it is using my key.

Comment: private keys are... private. that's why you need the password. it wouldn't be private if it did not require a password. sure you can make a private key without a password... but that's obviously less secure.

Comment: It didn't used to require a password.

Comment: Also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add your private key to ssh agent again. I faced same problem after Sierra update.

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) is a guide to add your key.

Comment: This sort of worked. I added the key successfully using the `ssh-add` command but if I restart the terminal I am forced to do it again. I also tried the -K option for the command to add it to the keychain but after a reboot I still have to enter the password.

Comment: Make sure that you have only one agent running, in my case, I need enter pw for each reboot, if you want 'the old behavior', follow [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @Vagner, `ssh-add -A` in my bash_profile fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the passphrase

https://stackoverflow.com/a/112409/2774776

or import the key into the key with passphrase into your Mac user’s keychain:

https://superuser.com/a/269570/365431

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  While the links you provided may answer the question, it's advisable to summarize and/or provide the relevant details that answer the question here.  Links often go stale making the answer useless.