# Storing SSH passphrase in memory but not saving it to the keychain persistently

Tags: keychain, ssh

Answers to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots) explain how to have SSH passphrases added to the keychain when they are entered.  Having recently upgraded from a previous version of OSX, I'm used to the passphrases being stored in memory but not in persistent storage.  If setting `UseKeychain yes` causes passphrases to be stored to disk, is there a way to prevent this?  IE I'd like to avoid having to re-enter them except after having rebooted.  It seems less than ideal to store a passphrase in a location protected with a potentially less secure password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `UseKeychain no` (the default) and run `ssh-add` *without* the `-K` option.

Note that this does not store the pass phrase in memory; instead, it causes `ssh-agent` to keep the decrypted key in memory, and subsequent uses of `ssh` will then work without the need to supply the pass phrase.

If you already have the pass phrase stored in the keychain, you'd need to use the `Keychain Access` application to find the pass phrase and delete it.