# Can Touch ID unlock a personal SSH key?

Tags: unix, ssh, touch-id

Is it possible to use the Touch ID fingerprint reader to unlock my SSH key?

I have a MacBook Pro with Touch Bar, and I have a traditional text passphrase for my SSH key right now.

I have noticed that I don't get a system dialog asking for my passphrase on 10.12, so this probably isn't a thing, but if I could do it, it would be AMAZING.

Comment: [OpenSSH 8.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) adds FIDO2 support. If there is a way to wire TouchID to a FIDO2 unlock, this should work. I have not tried doing so.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**:

One option is add your private SSH key to macOS Keychain, then use TouchID for Keychain authentication. You will want to use `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[your-private-key]` -- however on macOS 10.12 Sierra the feature needs to be enabled by editing editing `~/.ssh/config` and adding:

```
Host * (asterisk for all hosts or add specific host)
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile <key> (e.g. ~/.ssh/userKey)
```

For details, read:

1. [Permanently add your private key to Keychain so it is automatically available to SSH](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically)
2. [Saving SSH keys in macOS Sierra keychain](https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain)

**Original**:

At present TouchID unlocking of an SSH key is **not available** for macOS.

1. The [sudo-touchid](https://github.com/mattrajca/sudo-touchid) Xcode project demonstrates how to build a command line application that is TouchID enabled and fails over to a passcode dialog. It runs on the 2016 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar. However, it is for `sudo`, not ssh. This indicates that the idea is technically feasible.
2. The [Prompt 2](https://panic.com/prompt/) SSH client has TouchID support -- for iOS, not macOS. This indicates that comparable applications might become available from commercial developers.
3. One developer online started an [ssh touchid wrapper](https://github.com/ambrosechua/ssh-wrapper-touchid) project a few months ago -- although it is an empty project stub. This indicates that others may be asking a similar question to yours.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "then use Touch ID for Keychain authentication"? If I follow your steps I'm not asked to authenticate at all.

Comment: Can you update the instructions to make it more clear whether the first part of the first sentence applies to 10.12+?

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple options that will generate and store your private key in the Secure Enclave. Access to the keys can be gated either via Touch ID and/or a tap on an Apple Watch.

- [Secretive](https://github.com/maxgoedjen/secretive)
- [Secure Agent](https://secure-agent.lapanthere.com/)
- [Sekey](https://github.com/ntrippar/sekey)

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat tangential to my original question, but I have recently been using and very much like [Krypton](https://krypt.co), which gives me something a lot like TouchID unlocking. This solution stores the SSH key on my phone's secure enclave, and my computer and phone negotiate via bluetooth when I go to use the key. I get a confirmation popup on the phone and respond after unlocking *that.*

So! I get to do something that works similarly, but is (I think) a bit more secure than storing the key on my laptop (even with a passphrase), pretty definitely better than leaving it decrypted in my Keychain, and very usable to boot.

It also works as a U2F second factor for web services, using a browser plugin.

Comment: Wither, Krypton. Thanks Akamai :/.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS you can use the 1Password SSH/Git agent to unlock your key with TouchID:

For more info: [https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/agent/#:~:text=The%201Password%20SSH%20agent%20uses,even%20leaves%20the%201Password%20app](https://developer.1password.com/docs/ssh/agent/#:%7E:text=The%201Password%20SSH%20agent%20uses,even%20leaves%20the%201Password%20app).

Comment: Thanks for contributing!  Some feedback:  It's better to include the relevant portions here so readers don't have to go off-site for the answer and link back as a supporting resource.  Also, it would be helpful to show how this *directly* addresses the question being asked; regarding TouchID.

Comment: good lord is there a way I can mark my question as old, dumb, and answered so I stop getting notified about it

Answer (score -3):

You could easily write an wrapper to translate touchid calls into ssh and back again. Even further translate a ~ possible match into a range sequence (think close but incomplete painting) - no magic there. I used the camera for that before when touchid seemed like a tricorder feature from star trek :-)

Try making such App yourself, a good motivation to learn Swift! Apple has good doc's around all of their SDK's so after initial pain of Xcode you can do it in few days.

Seems like a good idea to use the feat. even when everybody will tell you of gazillions possible security risks that are, well, possible (like a lot of other things). You will need a dev account though (99$/year...), since self-signed apps cant access all macOS SDKs functionalities, touchID is (possibly) not accessible without signing.