# How can I use my SSH key with TouchID so that don't have to type in my passphrase each time, but still required my finger print at each log in?

Tags: mac, ssh, touch-id

I am trying to use my ssh key with touchID. As others suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically), I ran
`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/[my-private-key]` and modified my `.ssh/config` with

```
 Host *
   UseKeychain yes
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

which works and makes my key available from the Keychain however it doesn't force me to provide my fingerprint.
I would like to force the usage of TouchID to unlock my key every time when I try to ssh in, or at least once after opened the terminal client.

Comment: Do you have access to the sshd configuration of the systems you log into?

Comment: @nohillside yes

Comment: You need to configure passphrass-less access there.

Comment: That is how it is configured, just using ssh key to to ssh in, have no issue with that.

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: Same problem here... Has anybody been able to figure this out?