# MacOS 12 Monterey (M1) keeps asking my ssh passphrase every time

Tags: macos, ssh, monterey, apple-silicon

I tried to add this to ~/.ssh/config file, but it doesn't help. Seems like it doesn't work for macOS Monterey anymore.

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: Finally, I found a solution https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically#433667

Answer (score 12):

Prior to **MacOS Monterrey** the `-K` flag was used to add the key to the agent but since then and now in the new **MacOS Ventura 13**, we have a couple of different and more descriptive options:

```
--apple-use-keychain
--apple-load-keychain
```

> The `-K` and `-A` flags are deprecated and have been replaced by the these new flags, respectively.

Now, I also had to add this line to my `.zshrc` file in order for `ssh-add` to load my passphrase on every session:

```bash
ssh-add --apple-load-keychain -q
```

The `-q` flag is to prevent from showing this message in every shell session but not a must:

```
Identity added: /Users/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 (my@email.com)
```

Hopefully it will save some time to someone in the same situation as me after OS X upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. I've been meaning to find a solution to this issue for a while, and I just came across this. Much appreciated.

Comment: @DarrylYoung you're welcome, happy to red it helped you!